# How do I free() a non-heap object?

Tags: c, string, char, malloc, free

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int** intptrArray;
char word[50];
```

I'm trying to use free() on both the array and word after I allocate them using malloc in the function that comes after this. free(intptrArray) seems to work just fine but everytime I try free(word), free(*word), or free(&word), I get errors - most common is "attempt to free non-heap object".

How can I resolve this? TIA!

Comment: Why would you want to? What do you expect to happen as a result of freeing `word`?

Comment: You can only free memory returned by `malloc()`, `calloc()`, `realloc()`, etc.

Comment: Please post the [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) with complete code that *shows* how you use `malloc()` and `free()` instead of suppositions and descriptions.

Answer (score 7):

How do you free a non-heap object?  You don't.

The purpose of `free` is to make allocated heap memory available for other uses by the program.  So you should only pass to `free` pointer values that were returned from `malloc` / `calloc` / `realloc`.

Comment: Oh, I see. So even if I allocated space for word using malloc, I don't need to "release"/free up that memory?

Comment: @AlexiosNaval If you did then yes.  However because you defined it as `char word[50];` that means that you didn't.

Comment: @AlexiosNaval you can't allocate space for `word` using malloc

Answer (score 0):

> 'm trying to use free() on both the array **and word after I allocate
> them using malloc in the function that comes after this**.

It seems you do not understand how functions accept arguments that have an array type.

I can guess that what you are doing looks similar to the following program.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void f( char word[] )
{
    word = malloc( 50 * sizeof( char ) );
    strcpy( word, "Hello World!" );
    
    puts( word );
}

int main(void) 
{
    char word[50] = "Bye!";

    f( word );
    
    puts( word );
    
    return 0;
}
```

The program output

```
Hello World!
Bye!
```

As you can see the array `word` was not changed. Within the function you did not change the array `word` declared in main. When you passed the array to the function `f` it is implicitly converted to pointer of the type `char *`. This pointer (parameter) is a local variable of the function. So you changed the local variable. The array itself declared in main was neither changed nor reallocated. It has the automatic storage duration and it is the compiler that will free the declared array after the function main will finish its execution.

On the other hand, the allocated memory pointed to by the parameter `word` of the function `f` indeed must be freed. Otherwise there will be a memory leak. It can be done within the function for example like

```
void f( char word[] )
{
    word = malloc( 50 * sizeof( char ) );
    strcpy( word, "Hello World!" );
    
    puts( word );

    free( word );
}
```